# Dynamically adding members to a dynamic object

Tags: reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm looking for a way to add members dynamically to an dynamic object. OK, I guess a little clarification is needed...

When you do that :

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = 42;
```

The `Bar` property will be added dynamically at runtime. But the code still refers "statically" to Bar (the name "Bar" is hard-coded)... What if I want to add a property at runtime without knowing its name at compile time ?

I know how to do this with a custom dynamic object (I actually [blogged about it](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/10/08/c-4-0-implementing-a-custom-dynamic-object/) a few months ago), using the methods of the `DynamicObject` class, but how can I do it with *any* dynamic object ?

I could probably use the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface, but I don't understand how to use it. For instance, what argument should I pass to the `GetMetaObject` method ? (it expects an `Expression`)

And by the way, how do you perform reflection on dynamic objects ? "Regular" reflection and `TypeDescriptor` don't show the dynamic members...

Any insight would be appreciated !

Comment: In C# 6.0, *may be* you can write it like `foo.$Bar = 42;` :) Not sure if it's allowed for dynamic...

Comment: @nawfal, actually, that feature has been dropped... but anyway, `foo.$Bar` is just shorthand for `foo["Bar"]`

Comment: Thomas, didn't know about the feature being dropped (I'm glad about it), but oh yes, for a moment I overlooked the real requirement of your q.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is similar to Python's getattr/setattr functions.  There's no built in equivalent way to do this in C# or VB.NET.  The outer layer of the DLR (which ships w/ IronPython and IronRuby in Microsoft.Scripting.dll) includes a set of hosting APIs which includes an ObjectOperations API that has GetMember/SetMember methods.  You could use those but you'd need the extra dependency of the DLR and a DLR based language.

Probably the simplest approach would be to create a CallSite w/ one of the existing C# binders.  You can get the code for this by looking at the result of "foo.Bar = 42" in ildasm or reflector.  But a simple example of this would be:

```
object x = new ExpandoObject();
CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>> site = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(
            Binder.SetMember(
                Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                "Foo",
                null,
                new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }
            )
        );
site.Target(site, x, 42);
Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)x).Foo);
```

Comment: I need to take some time to make sure I really understand what this code is doing, but anyway it's working fine... Thanks !

Comment: Would it be possible to do this < .Net 4.0 using the DLR? It appears that the use of dynamic would preclude this.

Comment: The method above should not work properly. Setter call site requires 2 argument infos to be provided instead of 1. The correct definition will be: new[] 
          { 
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) 
          }

Answer (score 5):

The opensource framework [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey#dynamitey) will do this (available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dynamitey/)). It encapsulates while still caching the call site and binder code that @Dino-Viehland used.

```
Dynamic.InvokeSet(foo,"Bar",42);
```

It can also call many [other kinds of c# binder too](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#basic).

Answer (score 5):

ExpandoObject implements IDictionary<string,object> albeit explicitly. What this means is that you can simply cast the ExpandoObject to IDictionary<string,object> and manipulate the dictionary.

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = 42;
food = (IDictionary<string,object>)foo;
food["Baz"] = 54
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed ExpandoObject implements IDictionary, as I realized afterwards, so it is clearly the simplest solution in that case. However the scope of my question was wider: I was looking for a solution that would work with any dynamic object, not just ExpandoObject

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old post, but I thought I'd pass along [Miron Abramson solution](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/06/Create-you-own-new-Type-and-use-it-on-run-time-%28C%29.aspx) on how you can create your own type and add properties at runtime -- in case anyone else out there is looking for something similar.