# Invoke a member of a dynamic object with a name defined at runtime in a String

Tags: .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I want to access a property on an object while leveraging the DLR binding mechanism.

- I cannot use the native binding mechanism (`dynamic` keyword in C#) because I do not know the property name at compile-time;
- I cannot use reflection because it only retrieves static type information;
- casting to an `IDictionary<string, object>`, to my knowledge, only solves the case of dynamic classes that choose to implement that interface (such as `ExpandoObject`).

Here is the demonstration code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        obj.Prop = "Value";
        // C# dynamic binding.
        Console.Out.WriteLine(obj.Prop);
        // IDictionary<string, object>
        Console.Out.WriteLine((obj as IDictionary<string, object>)["Prop"]);
        // Attempt to use reflection.
        PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Prop");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(obj, new object[] { }));
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was finally able to do it by using the C# runtime binder. (I believe it should be possible to do that with a simpler binder implementation, but I was unable to write a working one - probably writing a "simple" implementation is already quite tough).

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;

    private class TestClass
    {
        public String Prop { get; set; }
    }

    private static Func<object, object> BuildDynamicGetter(Type targetType, String propertyName)
    {
        var rootParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var propBinder = Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, propertyName, targetType, new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });
        DynamicExpression propGetExpression = Expression.Dynamic(propBinder, typeof(object), 
            Expression.Convert(rootParam, targetType));
        Expression<Func<object, object>> getPropExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(propGetExpression, rootParam);
        return getPropExpression.Compile();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic root = new TestClass { Prop = "StatValue" };

        Console.Out.WriteLine(root.Prop);
        var dynGetter = BuildDynamicGetter(root.GetType(), "Prop");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(dynGetter(root));

        root = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        root.Prop = "ExpandoValue";

        Console.WriteLine(BuildDynamicGetter(root.GetType(), "Prop").Invoke(root));
        Console.Out.WriteLine(root.Prop);
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output:

```
StatValue
StatValue
ExpandoValue
ExpandoValue
```

Answer (score 3):

The opensource framework [dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) will do this (available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dynamitey/)). It uses that same api calls as the c# compiler.

```
Console.Out.WriteLine(Dynamic.InvokeGet(obj,"Prop"));
```

Comment: Is InvokeGet method available in .net core/.net standard?

Comment: Yes, I moved the methods to a new library to make a portable library back in the day. It's since become a .net standard

Answer (score 0):

You could use C# `dynamic` with runtime compilation to accommodate the requirement of the unknown property name.

An example:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();

d.Value = 7;

var helper = "" +
    "using System; " +
    "public class Evaluator " + 
    "{{ " + 
    "    public object Eval(dynamic d) {{ return d.{0}; }} " + 
    "}}";

var references = new string[] 
{ 
    "System.dll", 
    "System.Core.dll", 
    "Microsoft.CSharp.dll" 
};

var parameters = new CompilerParameters(references, "Test.dll");
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

var results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    parameters,
    String.Format(helper, "Value"));

dynamic exp = Activator.CreateInstance(
    results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Evaluator"));

Console.WriteLine(exp.Eval(d));
```

This works, but I doubt that this is the best option and if you need invoke method it can get a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass `DynamicObject` you can override [TrySetMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trysetmember.aspx) to store the properties by name in a local dictionary, and override [TryGetIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex.aspx) to enable retrieving them using the property name as a string. There's a pretty good example of this at the [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) page on MSDN.

This is not the fastest way to do it as it doesn't take advantage of dynamic dispatch and callsites (and other stuff I don't quite understand) as well as it could, but it will work. It'll end up looking like this:

```
dynamic myDynamicClass = new MyDynamic();

// Uses your TrySetMember() override to add "Value" to the internal dictionary against the key "Prop":
myDynamicClass.Prop = "Value";

// Uses your TryGetIndex override to return the value of the internal dictionary entry for "Prop":
object value = myDynamicClass["Prop"];
```

Comment: Thing is, I am working under the assumption that I do not control the dynamic object that I am consuming - it can be any object that implements IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a variant of this question: [Dynamically adding members to a dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079870/dynamically-adding-members-to-a-dynamic-object/2080581#2080581) but instead of wanting to add you're wanting to get the members - so just change the binder and the signature of the call site.  It looks like you've already figured out how to make the binder.