# Dynamically adding properties to a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, expandoobject

i have this

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.Name = attribute.QualifiedName.Name;
```

so , i know that d will have a property Name. Now if i don't know the name of the property at compile time , how do i add that property to the dynamic.
i found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079870/dynamically-adding-members-to-a-dynamic-object)

so, there is this complicated concept of call binders etc..which is tough to get in the first place.any simpler way of doing this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding unknown (at design time) properties to an ExpandoObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<string,object>)d)["test"] = 1;
//now you have d.test = 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a cleaner way

`var myObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;`
`myObject.Add("Country", "Ireland");`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this:-

```
Dictionary<string,object> coll = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    coll.Add("Prop1","hello");
    coll.Add("Prop2",1);
    System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject obj = dic.Expando();

//You can have this ext method to better help

public static ExpandoObject Expando(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> 
dictionary)
        {
            var expando = new ExpandoObject();
            var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
            foreach (var item in dictionary)
            {
                expandoDic.Add(item);
            }
            return expando;
        }
```